# Amazon S3 Node.JS method getObject() clarification on its parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have this code for Amazon Lambda:

```
const file_stream = s3.getObject({ Bucket: bucket, Key: filename });
```

This line of code would be used along with `exports.handler = async (event)` function.

In regards to the "Key" parameter, is the filename should be just the filename (ex. `filename.ext`), full directory for the filename (ex. `https://link/to/a/file/filename.ext`), or something else? (I am pretty much new in AWS S3 and Lambda)

Comment: var getParams = {
    Bucket: 'xyz, // your bucket name,
    Key: 'file.txt' // path to the object you're looking for
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume you have a bucket `my-bucket` and a file 'abc.txt' inside folder hierarchy like `2021/04/12`.

So you can do like below to get the object:

```
s3.getObject({ Bucket: 'my-bucket', Key: '2021/04/12/abc.txt' }).promise();
```

You can check the key value in console as well just click on the file you want to process and you can see key value under Properties `Object overview` tab.